# Django: Extract dict for save.method

Tags: django

Currently I am adding data to my model form in that way:new_order =

```
order.save(commit=False)
new_order.total_gross = total_amount
new_order.total_tax = total_tax_amount
new_order.total_gross_converted = total_amount  # TODO Marc
new_order.event = event
new_order.order_reference = session_order_reference
new_order.status = 'pending' # TODO Marc
new_order.save()
```

I am now wondering if there is a 'better'/cleaner way with a dict. Anyone did that before?

This is unfortunately doesn't work:

```
new_order_dict = {
    'total_gross': total_amount,
    'total_tax': total_tax_amount,
    'total_gross_converted': total_amount,
    'event': event,
    'order_reference': session_order_reference,
    'status': 'pending',
}

new_order = order.save(commit=False)
new_order.append(**new_order_dict)
new_order.save()
```

Comment: Where does this `new_order` comes from?

Comment: Use Update_or_Create with a dict of defaults? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem sorry I didn't wrote that clear `new_order = order.save(commit=False)`. Order is from a model form.

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to solve this is using `setattr(..)`:

```
for k, v in new_order_dict.items():
    setattr(new_order, k, v)
new_order.save()
```

This works since `setattr(x, 'y', z)` is equivalent to `x.y = z` (note that in `setattr(..)` we use `'y'` in a string). So we iterate through the `.items()` of the dictionary (an iterable of 2-tuples where each tuple contains a *key* `k` and *value* `v`), and then we call `setattr(..)` to set the attribute with the name `k` to `v`.

Finally we thus perform a `.save(..)`.

Comment: Amazing! Works perfectly. Thank you so much! (Will accept as best answer, as soon I can)